# Zend Regex Route help

Tags: regex, zend-framework, http-get, zend-route

I am trying to create a Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex route to process URLs in the following form:

`search?q=chicken/page=2` where the first regex subpattern would be `chicken` and second one would be `2`.  As for the second part where `page=2`, I want to make it optional if it is the first page, that is `page=1`. So another url such as `search?q=chicken` would also be valid and is equivalent to `search?q=chicken/page=1`.

Here is my attempt albeit without any success, but to give you a better picture of what I am trying to do.

```
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(             
            'search\?q=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:/page=(\d+))',
            array( 
                'page'=> '1',
             'module' => 'default', 
             'controller' => 'search', 
             'action' => 'index' ), 
            array( 1 => 'query', 2 => 'page' ),
            'search?=%s/page=%d');
        $router->addRoute('search', $route);
```

The problem here is I cant compose the correct regex.

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT #1

The correct regex, as pointed out by MA4, is `'search\?q=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:/page=(\d+))?'`

The real problem is pointed by Darryl.  Here is a little bit more info to put things into perspective.

My search text box and button

```
    <form action="/search" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Every time I press the `search` button, I get the search?q=[text] request.  How do I force it to go through the regex match route?

Here is what i want to do, however the code does not work

```
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('query')){
        // redirect success
    } else {
        $url = "search?q=" . $this->_getParam('q');            
        $this->_redirect(route('search'), array('code' => 301 ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/search?q=chicken/page=2` is not parsable by Zend Frameworks' router.  The router will only see `/search`.

The router relies on the Path Info provided by the server and anything after the ? is the query string.

You would need to use a path such as this:

```
/search/[word]        (default page 1)
/search/[word]/[page]
```

In which case your regex would become much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the input, now I know why my search button doesn't work.  I edited my original question for more details.

Comment: My answer is still the answer.  What you are trying to do is not possible with the request string `/search?q=chicken/page=2` will result in the pathinfo being `/search` and a single $_GET param of `q` having the value `chicken/page=2` - the Zend Framework router uses the pathinfo ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

make the second part optionnal by adding a `?` after it:

```
search\?q=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:/page=(\d+))?
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, the extra `?` does fix the regex, but my routing still doesn't work for the reason pointed out by Darryl.